# Validate XML with Schematron ISO version using C#

Tags: c#, schematron, ubl, peppol

Hi I have requirement where I have to validate a xml file against Schematron ISO version using C#. I have tried Saxon-HE , NMatrix.Schematron but its not working.

Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25366658/xml-schematron-validation-on-c-sharp-net-platform

Comment: What did you try with Saxon HE, how did it fail? Does the stylesheet from https://github.com/Schematron/schematron not work?